# Maintain Scroll Position of ASP Listbox Inside an ASP Update Panel

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have 4 asp listboxes inside of one asp updatepanel. The website is a webforms project using vb.net. These listboxes are acting as a filter for a database table. When you click on the first listbox, it updates the remaining listboxes relevant to the selection. You can also multi-select items inside these listboxes. This is very important.

The problem occurs with the scroll position of the listboxes resetting to the top when you select multiple items. Say you select the top item, and then scroll down to the 14th item and ctrl + click to select both. Well this causes the scroll position of the listbox to reset to the top after the partial postback caused by the update panel filtering the remaining listboxes. As you can imagine, this can get very annoying for my clients.

I've seen other solutions to maintaining scroll position of just the update panel, but not for controls inside the update panel. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question. What I did is that I leveraged the Trigger functionality of the update panels and enclosed the last 3 listboxes into their own update panel.

The first listbox doesn't need to be in an update panel because its contents don't have to change depending on the selections of the rest of the listboxes' contents. The second listbox I enclosed in its own update panel, and only added an asynchronous post back trigger for the first listbox. For the third and fourth listboxes, I also enclosed them in their own update panels, and added asynchronous triggers for each of the preceding controls respectively (so on third listbox update panel, I added 2 asynchronous triggers for the preceding controls, and 3 asynchronous for the preceding controls on the 4th listbox update panel).

Hope this helps someone else!